# Test Suite unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, test-suite

I have a test suite and I am trying to get it to work with the tests I have created. The test work if I run them individually but I want to run them all in a test suite. The code below show the test suite created:

```
import unittest

def suite():
    modules_to_test = ('TestAbsoluteMove', 'TestContinuousMove') # and so on
    alltests = unittest.TestSuite()
    for module in map(__import__, modules_to_test):
        alltests.addTest(unittest.findTestCases(module))
    return alltests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(defaultTest='suite')
```

I have placed this code into my test code to link up with the suite:

```
class AbsoluteMoveTestSuite(unittest.TestSuite):

def makeAbsoluteMoveTestSuite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestAbsoluteMove("BasicAbsolutePan"))
    suite.addTest(TestAbsoluteMove("VerifyAbsolutePan"))
    suite.addTest(TestAbsoluteMove("VerifyAbsoluteTilt"))
    suite.addTest(TestAbsoluteMove("VerifyAbsolutePanSpeed"))
    suite.addTest(TestAbsoluteMove("VerifyAbsoluteTiltSpeed"))
    return suite

def suite():
    return unittest.makeSuite(TestAbsoluteMove)
```

The error that is produced claim that there is no modules named 'TestAbsoluteMove' and TestContinuousMove'. Does anyone know how to get this code working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) makes this sort of thing a no-brainer. It will auto-detect your tests and run them as a suite. (You can also run specific tests by passing it a flag.)

Comment: I don't think adding an extra dependency is the right answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

TestAbsoluteMove is a class, and it needs to come from somewhere. Wherever your AbsoluteMoveTestSuite class is defined, you need to import TestAbsoluteMove.

Answer (score 2):

this is how I create my testsuite (loadTestFromTestCase detects your tests automatically)

```
def suite():
    """ returns all the testcases in this module """
    return TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(AbsoluteMoveTestSuite)
```

and to run them all at once I have a suite that incorporates all subsuites (notice all the imports, you will need to import them before they are available in your new module)

```
import sys
import unittest

import test.framework.asyncprocess as a
import test.framework.easyconfig as e
import test.framework.modulegenerator as mg
import test.framework.modules as m
import test.framework.filetools as f
import test.framework.repository as r
import test.framework.robot as robot
import test.framework.easyblock as b
import test.framework.variables as v
import test.framework.github as g
import test.framework.toolchainvariables as tcv
import test.framework.toolchain as tc
import test.framework.options as o
import test.framework.config as c


# call suite() for each module and then run them all
SUITE = unittest.TestSuite([x.suite() for x in [r, e, mg, m, f, a, robot, b, v, g, tcv, tc, o, c]])

# uses XMLTestRunner if possible, so we can output an XML file that can be supplied to Jenkins
xml_msg = ""
try:
    import xmlrunner  # requires unittest-xml-reporting package
    xml_dir = 'test-reports'
    res = xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output=xml_dir, verbosity=1).run(SUITE)
    xml_msg = ", XML output of tests available in %s directory" % xml_dir
except ImportError, err:
    sys.stderr.write("WARNING: xmlrunner module not available, falling back to using unittest...\n\n")
    res = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(SUITE)
```

Comment: xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output=xml_dir, verbosity=1).run(SUITE) was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

`unittest` is a bit of a pain to use like this. I would very much reommend that you follow Alison's advice a look at `nose` or use my personal favourite Python testing tool [py.test](http://codespeak.net/py/dist/test/). Just create functions following a specific naming convention and let it rip! The whole xUnit thing doesn't really fit into Python territory.